# Хочу удалить некоторые символы из элемента списка

Tags: python

```
with open('Текст2.txt') as f:
    my_lines = f.readlines() #['The first line.\n','The last line.\n']
    print(my_lines)
```

Вот моя программа, которая выводит список,данный после хэш-тэга.

Как можно убрать "\n" из списка?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `my_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]`

Comment: Вместо readlines() прописать f.read().split('\n')

Comment: @AlioshcaZ, лучше использовать более специализированный метод: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines строки файлов, к сожалению, не только `'\n'` разделяются

Comment: @gil9red Да, согласен, я писал про данный конкретный вопрос и удаление '\n'.

Answer (score 2):

Если считывать весь файл, то для разделения на список строк, можно использовать [str.splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
with open('Текст2.txt') as f:
    my_lines = f.read().splitlines()
    print(my_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('Текст2.txt') as f:
    my_lines = f.readlines() #['The first line.\n','The last line.\n']
    for i in range(len(my_lines)):
        my_lines[i] = my_lines[i].replace("\n", "")
    print(my_lines)

my_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

Добавлю ответы из комментариев, чтобы сделать ответ полноценным.

---

[nomnoms12](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/339283/nomnoms12):

```
with open('Текст2.txt') as f:
    my_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
    print(my_lines)
```

Comment: спасибо,сработало